# Return all wordpress custom posts in specific multidimensional array

Tags: php, wordpress, multidimensional-array, custom-post-type

How can I get all custom posts (post_type=family_guy) with their ID and all of their tags in multidimensional array?

Here is exactly how I would like my array to look like:

```
$array = array("1" =>   Array(
                           "Peter1",
                           "Lois1",
                           "Megan1"
                     ),  
          "2" =>   Array(
                           "Peter2",
                           "Lois2",
                           "Megan2"
                     ),
          "3" =>   Array(
                            "Peter3",
                            "Lois3",
                            "Megan3"
                     ),
         "4" =>   Array(
                            "Peter4",
                            "Lois4",
                            "Megan4"
                     )
          );
```

In this array, keys will be custom posts IDs, and values will be all tags of that custom post.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: can you provide us code you have written to register this in function.php.i want to check which taxonomy you have applied, or you have applied or not first.

Comment: I have implemented custom-post with plugin Custom Post Types. I am able to search for this custom types, but I can not get this array that contain IDs and tags.

Comment: to get this you have to register a texonomy first and mention in post type registration arguments, and then you can get all this stuff. i am asking like for this:$args = array(
  'labels' => $labels,
  'public' => true,
  'publicly_queryable' => true,
  'show_ui' => true,
  'query_var' => true,
  'rewrite' => true,
  'capability_type' => 'post',
  'hierarchical' => false,
  'menu_position' => null
   );  

 //register what we just set up above
 register_post_type('post-type-name', $args);

Comment: post_tag taxonomy is already registered with this plugin. I am not using custom taxonomy. I am getting post like any other via standard query $args=array(
  'post_type' => 'family_guy',
  'post_status' => 'publish',
  'posts_per_page' => -1
);
$my_query = new WP_Query($args);

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something along these lines should help, in functions.php

```
function cpt_tag_list() {
    $types = get_post_types(array(
        '_builtin' => false  // This returns only custom post types
        'public' => true     // Not necessarily right, but consider this, you may need to filter out CPTs made by plugins.
    ));

    $op = array();
    $i = 0;

    foreach ($types as $cpt) {
        $i++;

        $posts_in_cpt = new WP_Query("posts_per_page=-1&post_type={$cpt}");

        $tags_used = array();

        foreach ($posts_in_cpt as $post) {
            $tags_used[] = get_tags($post->ID);
        }

        $op[(string) $i] = array_unique($tags_used);
    }

return $op
}
```

And then invoke in your site by calling cpt_tag_list();

Apologies if I've made any errors in this, I've not had chance to test it, but hopefully the gist of it is there for you.

Comment: I understood the logic. Thank you.